# Why its symmetric and transitive relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

R is relation on A = {1,2,3,4}

R = {(1,1), (2,2), (3,3)}

Can you explain me why R is symmetric and transitive ?

If its symmetric then there is supposed to be (1,2) (2,1) and for transitive (1,2) (2,3).

Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you said a bit more about where you are having trouble. The relation satisfies the definitions, so which parts are you having trouble with?

Comment: So if R would be {(1,1), (2,2), (3,3) (4,4) } it only be reflexive right?

Comment: Then it would also be reflexive (and still symmetric and transitive).

Comment: Then it is reflexive but *also* symmetric and transitive. The rule $(a,b)\in R\Rightarrow (b,a)$ is not broken. The rule $(a,b)\in R\wedge(b,c)\in R\Rightarrow (a,c)\in R$ is also not broken.

Comment: If $S=R\cup\{(1,2)\}$ where $R$ is the relation mentioned in your comment then $S$ is reflexive, but is *not* symmetric. This because $(1,2)\in S$ and $(2,1)\notin S$. It still is transitive. If $T=S\cup\{(2,3)$ then $T$ is reflexive but *not* transitive. This because $(1,2)\in T$ and $(2,3)\in T$ but $(1,3)\notin T$.

Comment: Tobi and Vera, thanks for explanation, its more clearly now.

Comment: @Dimitry, just read the definitions of "symmetric" and "transitive" very carefully. For example, for symetric: $\forall \:a,\:b\:\in \:X,$ if(!!!) $a\:R\:b\:\Rightarrow \:b\:R\:a.$. In your $R$, the rule is still working, but in empty. Just go every couple in $R$ and see if the opposite couple is also there. for example, $\:\left(2,2\right)\in R$, and the "opposite" is again $\left(2,2\right) $, that we know that in $R$.

Comment: The confusion comes from the aRb and bRa definition, because i think a and b are supposed to be different numbers.

Comment: Does  {(1,1), (2,2), (3,3) (4,4)} antisymmetric ?

Comment: My best guess is you are having a hard time understanding the definitions.  Please include the definitions you are struggling with (symmetric, reflexive) in the body of your Question.

Comment: "because i think a and b are supposed to be different numbers." This is simply not the case. The definition includes the case $a=b$. In you case you have only such pairs.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of symmetric is that for each $(a,b) \in R$  one has $(b,a) \in R$ as well.

Note that this definition includes the case $a=b$ though in this case the  implication is trivial.

Now, your example is somewhat peculiar in that you only have pairs of the form $(a,a)$. But this really does not matter. For each $(a,b) \in R$ you do have  $(b,a )\in R$, and that is all that is relevant.

The same reasoning applies for the "transitive." Again, some or all of $a,b,c$ can be equal.